# Storing Values in columns alphabetic?

Tags: database, schema

Is there any benefit to storing content alphabetic in columns? Maybe make lookups faster? If yes then when i add new lookup values to my tables do i need to rebuild the PK for the lookup values to fit in the new text? Say a table like this:

City_tbl
city_id: example: 1120
City_name: example: New York.

If I need to add Chicago to it, do i add it at the bottom of the list with the next ID which may be 2000 or do i inset it after the city in alphabetic order which would mean I need to update the PK Id of all following IDs by 1.

Only benefit I know about is when I have to manually add lookup values without querying the database I can quickly check the lookup value list for exiting items with ease. But not sure if it may make lookups faster or something if the system knows the text is in alphabetical order.

Comment: Even if you were to set up such a scheme how would the system know such a correlation exists? I'm not sure any products could either detect this or take advantage of this arrangement.

Comment: Don't try to invent your own 'improvements' to a database. Chances are, if it was worth doing the developers (who are smarter than me and you) would have already done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I see no value in it.  Better to use a proper primary key and add an index to the column.  The people who have spent years writing relational databases know how to optimize access far better than you do.

I'd make the PK column auto increment, leaving the updating to the database.  I'd add an index  to the city name column so you can search by name as quickly as possible.

You're presuming that you understand something about the physical storage of the database.  At best, your efforts will have no effect; at worst, you'll screw up the fast access that a properly indexed b-tree will already give you.